# Determine the value of c given joint PDF.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

[image: equation]

I am having trouble finding c. I know I must set the entire equation to **1**. I am just not sure of what the integration bounds are since the equation is from **0 <= x <= y <= 1**.

If anyone could point me in the right direction for integrating I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: The integration is $\int_0^1dy\int_0^ydx\,cx(1-x)$.  Does this help?

Answer (score 0):

Note that $f(x,y)=0$ where $0\leq x\leq y<\infty$ is not satisfied. Since the total probability mass must equal 1, you have the equation
$$1=\int\int f(x,y)dxdy=\int_0^1 \int_0^y cx(1-x)dxdy = c \int_0^1 \left( \frac{y^2}{2} - \frac{y^3}{3} \right) dy =\frac{c}{12}$$
Hence, $c=12$.

Comment: Note that $$\int_0^1\int_0^y6x(1-x)dxdy=\int_0^1\int_x^16x(1-x)dydx=\int_0^16x(1-x)^2dx$$ is $$\int_0^16(1-x)x^2dx=\left.2x^3-\tfrac32x^4\right|_0^1=\tfrac12\ne1$$

Comment: @Did: my mistake, thank you. I have edited my answer and removed the error.